# How to sort String value 75,74,105,61,76?

Tags: sorting, kotlin

Sorting is not working Kotlin using `sortedArrayDescending()` function.

I tried this method:

```kotlin
var temp1 = "75,74,105,61,76"
println("1st Value:: "+temp1)
var temp2 = temp1.split(",").toTypedArray()
println("2nd Value:: "+Arrays.toString(temp2))
var temp3 = temp2.sortedArrayDescending()
println(Arrays.toString(temp3))
```

Output is:

```
1st Value:: 75,74,105,61,76  
2nd Value:: [75, 74, 105, 61, 76]  
[76, 75, 74, 61, 105]
```

Why is 105 not in the first place?

Comment: Why do you expect 105 to be in first place? You're sorting the array (lexicographically) in descending order, so it will be last, because `'1'` < `'6'` < `'7'`.

Comment: This sorts `String`s, not numbers... The numbers here are considered *words* and those are compared character by character, which means anything with a leading 1 is likely to be at the end of a descendingly sorted collection, no matter how many characters it has!

Comment: Did any of the answers help you? :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`sortedByDescending`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sorted-by-descending.html) function to sort strings, which contain ints, by descending order:

```
val sortedTemp = "75,74,105,61,76"
            .split(",")
            .sortedByDescending { it.toInt() }
```

Comment: I think this is not efficient, since the lambda `{ it.toInt() }` will be invoked on each comparison during the sorting.

Comment: The whole purpose of this String of numbers is already inefficient, and `sortedByDescending ` is inlined, so that's not a big deal. The problem, though, is it creating lists upon lists in the background.

Comment: @MrPNG true, but if that is the use case having some numbers comma-separated in a string, we have to take it as is. Inlining won't solve that the same conversion code is running several times for the same element, which is not necessary. That's why I do the mapping first, which also increases readability.

Answer (score 0):

You are sorting strings rather than numbers, just convert each `String` to `Int` first and then sort the list of Ints using [`sortedDescending`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sorted-descending.html).

```
val strOfNumbers = "75,74,105,61,76"
val sortedNumbers = strOfNumbers.split(',').map(String::toInt).sortedDescending()
```

`sortedNumbers` will be:

> [105, 76, 75, 74, 61]

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin doesn't offer a standard way of comparing strings while considering numeric values within it.

If you want to compare all elements without converting them to numbers you could compare by string length first and then by the string itself:

```kotlin
"75,74,105,61,76"
    .split(',')
    .sortedWith(compareByDescending<String> { it.length }.thenByDescending { it })
```

Result: `[105, 61, 74, 75, 76]`

There are two caveats:

- It may not work properly if there are other characters than just digits.
- It may not work properly if numbers have leading zeros.